# Blender: Применение модификатора Wireframe для НЕсплошного объекта

Tags: 3d, blender, mesh

Мне нужно придать объём рёбрам меш-объекта, а грани оставить невидимыми. Для этого использую модификатор `Wireframe`. Проблемы начинаются, когда объект не является замкнутым (т.е. у него отсутствуют некоторые грани). В этом случае в полученном каркасе на границах с отсутствующими гранями появляются "дырки".

Исходный объект:
[image: До]

Вид после применения модификатора `Wireframe`:
[image: После]

Можно ли это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно нажать галочку Boundary:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]